# Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records. error datagridview?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estuve desarrollando una aplicacion en windows form pero al querer actualizar el datagridview y guardarlo en la base de datos ocurre este error:

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

todo dentro del metodo `private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`

```
SqlCommand sqlcmm = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Cuenta_{todayDate}", connection);
SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmm);
SqlCommandBuilder sqlcmmBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapt);
sqlAdapt.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
```

justamente cuando estoy editando manualmente aparece este error al editar una celda sin un patron en especifico despues de un momento editando. Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta pasando en este caso, es que los datos en la `DB` fueron modificados después de que hiciste la consulta original.

El problema es que el update utiliza una concurrencia optimista para buscar los datos, entonces escribe un query de la forma

```
UPDATE (A,B) SET A = valorA, B = valorB WHERE A=ValorAanterior and B=ValorBAnterior
```

Donde:

ValorX es el nuevo valor
ValorXAnterior es el valor que tenia ese campo antes de cambiarlo.

Entonces exactamente no esta encontrando esa fila para hacer el update.

Para solucionarlo, vas a tener que revisar mejor la estructura de tu programa y ver quien mas puede estar afectando esa columna.

Como nota al margen, si tu tabla es `Cuenta_{todayDate}` y ese todayDate quiere decir que haces una tabla por dia, entonces quiere decir que tu base de datos esta muy mal diseñada.

Comment: El query que utiliza es un poco confuso, talvez necesito  programar mejor con sql. Ademas resolvi el problema de una manera muy floja y guardo con las cambios con un boton en lugar de guardar cada cambio cada vez que cambio una celda. Pero a que se refiere con la base de datos mal diseñada? Que error estoy cometiendo? Te agradeceria si pudieras ayudarme.

Comment: Ahora editare el query, para ver si lo entendes mejor. tenes una tabla por dias? si es asi, esta mal diseñada (es lo que se puede suponer por tu consulta)

Comment: Vale, es que el query que me genera el "SqlComandBuilder" es diferente a lo que planteas. Si, una tabla por dia supongo que es una mala idea jaja. Quisiera saber por cuales razones es mala el diseñar o crear una tabla por dia?

Comment: que query te genera el update? una tabla por dia es tan malo, que no me alcanzan los caracteres aca. para empezar, si tenes que buscar algo y no sabes de que dia es, donde lo vas a buscar? y ademas, no alcanza con agregar la fecha a cada registro?

Comment: UPDATE [Data_management] SET [Cantidad] = p1, [Total] = p2, [Cliente] = p3, [datedata] = p4 WHERE (([id] = p5) AND ((p6 = 1 AND [Cantidad] IS NULL) OR ([Cantidad] = p7)) AND ((p8 = 1 AND [Total] IS NULL) OR ([Total] =p9)) AND ((p10 = 1 AND [Cliente] IS NULL) OR ([Cliente] = p11)) AND ((p12 = 1 AND [datedata] IS NULL) OR ([datedata] = p13)))

Comment: P(n) -> parametro. Este me genera no se pero este query no lo entiendo.

Comment: el objectivo que tenia en mente al crear uno por dia era el de consultar individualmente cada tabla sin necesidad de agregar una fecha como planteas. Si es tan pesima pues tendre que preguntar esto en otra seccion. Muchas gracias por cierto

Comment: no es pesima. es mas que pesima. y siento decirlo asi, pero que problema hay en consultar una tabla con fecha y poner una clausula where? si pensas que eso es malo, tal vez deberias volver a revisar tus conocimientos sobre base de datos. y ese query no esta mal, esta revisando un monton de campos que no son clave, para setear los otros campos. es lo mismo que yo escribi. (solo pone un par de chequeos mas, por si el campo es nulo y cosas asi) pero los p son los valores actuales y los valores anteriores.